# How many Jōyō Kanji are identical to simplified Hanzi?

Tags: kanji, chinese

How many Jōyō Kanji are identical to simplified Hanzi?

If we need to define a restriction for the simplified Hanzi, I would suggest
[List of Frequently Used Characters in Modern Chinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Commonly_Used_Characters_in_Modern_Chinese).

Comment: Originally, I was thinking to upvote this, but there's a *very* important qualification I think the question needs. Can you tell us what you mean by "identical"? Specifically, do you mean (a) same number of strokes or (b) same strokes from a technical standpoint, (c) would look the same if written by native writers of each language, or (d) are unicode identical? or ...

Comment: Just to make sure I know what I want, can you clarify what you mean by (b)?

Comment: I don't know simplified Hanzi, but to give an example look here: http://moji.tekkai.com/zoom/%E7%B6%9A/page.html . The 教科書体 and the 楷書体 would be "identical" under (a) but not (b), (c), and (d). Stoke order seems to differ widely between languages and users for 必 (so we get some (a) and (c) and (d)). 判 is written with the top two strokes either like 八 or ソ -- but that would be (a), (b), and (d) in many cases. See http://moji.tekkai.com/zoom/%E5%88%A4/page.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I have no knowledge of the subject, I am quoting from an academic paper:

[日本・中国・台湾・香港の基礎漢字1945字字体一覧表の作成に向けて](https://www5.cuhk.edu.hk/jas/jas_media/staff/kojima/10-1945-word-style.pdf)
(香港中文大学日本研究学科、Senior Instructor、兒島慶治)

According to the author of this paper, the number is 1,165. (See page 4.)

Note that there were 1,945 [常用漢字]{じょうようかんじ} when this paper was written.  Currently, that number has increased to 2,136.

So, the current number you are looking for would be a little over 1,165.

Also, this number from the paper includes minor differences as well. The paper notes (page 5):

> 更に極論すれば、例えば日中間で字体が異なるとされた約40％の漢字の中にも、「为(為)、异(異)、伟(偉)、卫(衛)、杰(傑)、洁(潔)、听(聴)」のように字体の差異が顕著なものと、「低(低)、唐(唐)、德(徳)、毒(毒)、肺(肺)、反(反)、鼻(鼻)、隆(隆)」のようにかなり微妙な差のものが含まれている。

(See also: [screenshot of the above quote from the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdae6.png))

On page 6, the paper estimates that about 170 of the characters that are different only display minor differences. It also notes that "minor difference" is not a clearly defined objective term:

> まだ全体的な整理を終えていない中間的な整理状況ではあるが、日中間での字体が異なるとされた771字中、168字（約22％）の字体差の低い字種があると言える。この整理においては、“糸”編の簡略は字体差が低いと見て数えたが、“言”・“金”・“魚”・“貝”編等は字体差がかなりあるとして、168字には整理しなかった為に、今後の整理如何によっては、更に字体差が低いと部類分けられる字種が増えるものと思う。